# Why does this return Infinity? (Java)

Tags: java, math, types, casting, type-conversion

Im trying to find the result of 1/1 + 1/4 + 1/9 + 1/16 + 1/25 ...

These is the lines I wrote that give the result `Infinity`:

```
public class BaselProblem {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int testLimit = 100000;
        double sum = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i<testLimit; i++) 
        {
            sum = sum + 1.0/(i*i);
        }
        System.out.println(sum);
    }
}
```

Changing `1.0/(i*i)` to `1/(1.0*i*i)` gives the correct result `1.6449240667982423`. Why is it that only the 2nd form work but not the 1st?

Also, because `(i*i) > 1`, then `1.0/(i*i)` should be `< 1`, so how can it leads to in `Infinity`?

Comment: `i*i` will overflow `int` and become negative or zero. But `1.0*i*i` is a double, not subject to the same kind of overflow. You could also use a `long`

Comment: The weird thing is: it's the sum of 100000 numbers, each of which is <1, so the sum should be <100000, not Infinity

Comment: You _think_ that each number is `<1`, but it is not when `i` reaches 65536.

Answer (score 7):

Because your `testLimit` as well as your `i` are defined as `int`. Since you put the expression `i*i` in parentheses, it will be calculated first, and will try to find the multiple of two integers - which will reach overflow pretty quickly and reset to zero.

Specifically, when `i` reaches 2¹⁶, `i*i` will be 2³². This means 1 followed by 32 zeros in binary, of which, only the 32 zeros are kept, which means zero. (Thanks @templatetypedef).

Therefore, you'll have a number divided by zero, which is infinity.

Change your loop declaration so that `i` is `double`. Or multiply by a double (1.0) on the *left hand* of `i*i`. This will cause the expression to be changed into `double` *before* multiplying by the second `i`.

Comment: Specifically, when i = 2^16, then i * i = 2^32, which (modulo 2^32) is equal to zero.

Comment: I havent test this, but I suppose if I wrote `1/(i*i*1.0)` then it would still give the same Infinity error as before, since `i*i` is evaluated to 0 before being typecast to double?

Answer (score 2):

Java integer have a maximum value of 2,147,483,647.  You're eventually surpassing that maximum with the integer that results from i*i.

If you do 1.0*i*i, you're converting the result to a double which can hold a maximum value of 1.79769313486231570E+308.

Your maximum value for i*i will be 10,000,000 which a double can hold, but an integer can't.